# API call field delete with delete_values parameter not working

Tags: python, podio

When performing an API call to delete a field in an app, the field is deleted at the template level. However the *delete_values* parameters is not doing the job when setting it up to *true*

```
## my python code using the requests library
url = 'https://api.podio.com/app/16200981/field/125619360'
data = {'delete_values': True}
request = requests.delete(url, headers=self._get_headers(), data=data)
```

The call is a success with a response body

```
{"revision": 29}
```

However none of the item's values for this field are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The "delete_values" parameter has to be in the URL and not in the body.

```
https://api.podio.com/app/16200981/field/125619360?delete_values=true
```

so the code

```
url = 'https://api.podio.com/app/16200981/field/125619360'
data = {'delete_values': True}
request = requests.delete(url, headers=self._get_headers(), params=data)
```